# Indy: TidMessage removes all accents, How to disable this?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I am sending e-mails using the indy components `TidSMTP` and `TidMessage`.

The mails I recieve are without accents.

If I do for example:

```
MyTIdMessage.Body.Text := 'Tèst';
```

As i recieve the e-mail I see "Test" instead of "Tèst"

Is there a way to tell TIdMessage not to ignore accents or is this bug?

Note: I am using Indy 10.5.8.0

Comment: which version of delphi are you using? I just made a test with Delphi XE/Indy 10.5.7 and it works very well, sending trough exchange server (ignoring what version) to gmail.

Comment: Accents require the use of Unicode, which is not supported in the VCL/RTL prior to Delphi 2009.  Indy has to jump through a lot of extra manual hoops to support Unicode in Delphi 2007 and earlier, so it is always possible that we missed something here and there.

Comment: AFAIK accents do not need Unicode - just a content transfer encoding and charset that supports them. For example with charset="iso-8859-1" and Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Comment: Of course characters beyond the 7 bit range must be properly encoded using the transfer encoding format, i.e. using quoted-printable "più" becomes "pi=F9". Does Indy encodes a message properly? Hope so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to set the correct Enconding, ContentTransferEncoding and CharSet. Being one of the oldest protocol, mail is designed to be used by computers using only 7 bits, and non US-ASCII characters thereby needs to be encoded. There are some different ways (quoted-printable, ecc.)

Also check the OnInitializeISO event.

Comment: Thanks the solution was `MyIdMessage.Encoding := meDefault;`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the correct CharSet by doing this

```
MyIdMessage.CharSet := 'US-ASCII';
```

the string values are listed in IdCharsetNames array.

Comment: US-ASCII does not look the most accent-friendly character set. For most Western European language I'd use ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15 (euro, and full Finnish/French support) if using UTF-8 is not an option. Windows-1252 is almost alike ISO-8859-1, but also includes -15 characters (with different codepoints). Other languages needs different character sets (or UTF).

Comment: 'US-ASCII' was only an example of how to set it, I intended them to use the char set suited their needs.